# SQL, having some trouble with json_agg & json_build_object

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need some help with SQL and JSON... Each casino has many deposits...
I'm trying to group each casinos deposit objects into a column in
json format.

**Unfortunately I seem to be missing something since I now get all deposit objects of all casinos into each "deposits" column on every casino row.**

**I want each deposits column to only have the deposit objects for that particular casino.**

Any ideas?

```
SELECT casino.id
      , casino."name"
      , json_agg(json_build_object('name', d."name", 'logo', d.logo)) as deposits
      --
    FROM public."Casino" casino
    --
    left join "DepositsOnCasinos" doc 
    on doc."casinoId" = casino.id 
    --
    left join "Deposit" d 
    on d.id = doc."depositId" 
    --
    GROUP BY casino.id, casino."name";
```

Comment: Can you reproduce your issue with sample data in a fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/btGcOH30?

Comment: will try, but just made the query a little bit more clear

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using:

jsonb_agg(distinct jsonb_build_object('name', d."name", 'logo', d.logo)) as deposits